# Customizing features in Repository design classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern

I could be probably wrong in the manner I am thinking the things will work
but I am really confused as I am using repository design pattern for the first time.
The problem is that the repository class will only have

GetaLL(), GetALLByID(), Update() or Save().

But what If I need to extract the records such that I have groupofUsers in one table
and for that each group I need to count how many users are there in each group. The user table is a different table.

The relation can be assumed as "UserGroup" as parent table which have unique 
usergroups but this UserGroup table has a key which will be foreign key in 
another table "Users". There could be many users in a group and similary with this
I need to find out how many roles are under the same table i.e "UserGroup".
This is another table "roles" which will have "UserGroups" in the same way as 
it wasin "users" table.

And here is how I ahve to get the records. My repository only have

```
 public abstract class Repository<T>
        where T : class
    {
        private readonly IDbSet<T> _dbset;

    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return this._dbset;
        }
}
```

And in controller I am calling it as below:

```
private readonly Repository<UserGroup> _GroupRepository;

    public IEnumerable<UserGroupModel> GetListedGroups()
        {
            var list = this._GroupRepository.GetAll();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a new class which derived from `Repository<T>` and add new methods in it.

```
public class UserGroupRepository : Repository<UserGroup>
{
    public UserCountInGroups GetUserCountInGroup()
    {
        // Do something with this._dbset here.
    }
}
```

So in the controller you use `UserGroupRepository` instead of `Repository<UserGroup>`

```
private readonly UserGroupRepository _GroupRepository;

public IEnumerable<UserGroupModel> GetListedGroups()
{
    var list = this._GroupRepository.GetAll();
    var userCount = this._GroupRepository.GetUserCountInGroup();
    // Do something here.
}
```

Comment: But it will be calling database two times and then if suppose I need to get the roles count also the I would again have to write another method for roles count and moreover the output is aligned in the table format like below:
UserGroup   GroupNAme   TotalUsers   TotalRoles
1                      Admin                      5                    10

Comment: @Sweetie I think you should put that detail and data model in question.